# TYPO3 news and realurl with two detail pages

Tags: php, typo3, realurl, tx-news

I've got something weird with news and realurl. I have two detail pages (one called "article" and one "blog-article"). The weird thing is that I can call "mysite.com/article/my-super-article-1" AND "mysite.com/blog-article/my-super-article-1". Both are responding.

The news records are stored in separated folder. Blog articles are stored in pid x and other articles in pid y...

I want that the news records with pid x are only accessible with "/article/..." and the ones with pid y only by "/blog-article/...". Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Jérémie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting `plugin.tx_news.settings.detail.checkPidOfNewsRecord = 1` in TypoScript the detail view checks if the news record's pid is in one of the defined pages in the plugin configuration.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!